# ClassCastException when loading classes from jar file

Tags: java, generics, casting

We're working on a map-reduce framework project from scratch.
When receiving the .jar file to get classes,
the generic types that we defined (key, value) caused a cast type problem.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: keysvalues.Key1 cannot be cast to keysvalues.Key1`

Comment: Show me your code please.

Comment: Sounds like a classloader issue. If two classloaders load the same `.class` file, then each of those loads will produce a different class -- even though everything about those classes (fields, methods, etc) is the same. And, just like you can't cast a String to a Map, you can't map a Key1 from one classloader to a Key1 from another classloader; they're different classes.